# Why place of MA in MB then copy from MB to IR rather than going straight from MA to IR

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

During the fetch stage of the fetch-execute cycle, why are the contents of the cell whose address is in the MA (memory address register) placed in MB (memory buffer) then copied to IR (instruction register), rather than placing the contents of address of MA directly in the IR?